# Nested repeater and datasource

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a repeater nested in an other repeater.
My question is: is it possible to generate other ItemTemplate components with datasource.
If yes, how can I do it ?
For example:

```
ItemTemplate1 of parentRepeater
    A
    B
    C
ItemTemplate2 of parentRepeater
    D
    E
    F
```

It means that ItemTemplate of childRepeater is changed for each ItemTemplate of parentRepeater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1"
                     onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" >

                <ItemTemplate> 
                         <!--Outer repeater -->
                            <asp:repeater id="repeater2" runat="server">
                                <itemtemplate>

                                     <!--Inner repeater repeater -->

                                      </itemtemplate>
                            </asp:repeater>

                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

`

Here is Back end code

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        //it return current row (think in terms of nested loops)
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem; 

        // get value of that row
        int postID = Convert.ToInt32(drv["PostID"]); 


        //do what ever you want to do
        Repeater2.DataSource =  //some data like you did in outer repeater
        Repeater2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: it just one of column name of outer repeater DataSet.

Comment: if you don't want to get values from outer repeater than you can skip this part and just assign DataSource to `Repeater2`

Comment: If I assign `DataSource` to `Repeater2`, the `Repeater2` is not changed for each `ItemTemplate` of `repeater1`

Comment: I have edited code, Please see it and ask if you still have confusion.

Comment: For example, I have 3 lists as 3 `datasource`. How can I use these lists to bind to `repeater2`

Comment: I could't understand what you ask. Ok let me explain it :

For every of `Repeater1` , `Repeater1_ItemDataBound` will be called and then what ever data you have assigned to `Repeater2` in function will be displayed in inner repeater.

Comment: For example, I have a a webpage to show multiple choice question:
Question 1:(It is `ItemTemplate` of the repeater1)
     A. abc
     B. cde
     C. egh
Question 2:(It is also the `ItemTemplate` of repeater1)
A.  qwe
B: rty
C: yui
`repeater2 ` ItemTemplate should have change datasource to make the option is different from other question

Comment: HERE IS YOUR CODE 
https://gist.github.com/abdullahtariq1171/e77acd041bdfd34f7016

Comment: I have got my answer. Thank you so much !

Comment: Now you can at least mark my answer "Accepted" .. so that i can get some credit :P

Comment: Okay, although it is not completed thoroughly ^^!

Comment: If its not OK then no problem. Take care.

Comment: I have found the solution by myself. Thank you so much ^^!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have them alternate back and forth between two templates, then use [`AlternateItemTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.alternatingitemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        This came from ItemTemplate.
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternateItemTemplate>
        This came from AlternateItemTemplate.
    </AlternateItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is commonly used when you want to vary the background color of each row in a table.